# How to use 1x,2x and 3x .png images in MAUI iOS?

Tags: maui

I know we have to use .svg image format instead of 1x,2x,3x .png image format and MAUI will handle it, but I am currently migrating my existing Xamarin Forms app to MAUI and it is difficult to convert all my existing 1x,2x,3x .png images into .svg images format.

If I use 1x,2x,3x .png image format then app is giving error

> "One or more invalid file names were detected.  File names must be lowercase, start and end with a letter character, and contain only alphanumeric characters or underscores"

[image]

Is there any way we can use 1x,2x,3x .png in MAUI?

Comment: You don't "have to use" svg.  They are supported, not required.

Comment: @Jason I updated question with error image. Please check.

Comment: it says the filename cannot contain special characters only alphanumeric characters or underscore are allowed. And your filename "unselected@2x" contains "@" in it.

Comment: @NSubedi This is how we have to add images in iOS. This is iOS naming conventions that we have to use unselected@2x and unselected@3x in image name.

Comment: Make an asset catalog. Currently this has to be done manually. See [How to scale images for iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1181293/how-to-scale-images-for-ios-on-maui). Skip past the .svg part, down to "If you still want to define "@x" file ..."

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I tried the solution given in link. MAUI App is not allowing me to create folder with name "Assets.xcassets" and "CustomImage.imageset".

Comment: Make a new issue at `github maui issues`; see if you get a response. Link back to here, and include link to "How to scale images for iOS on MAUI?" above. List the exact steps you took. Could also make a `Xamarin.iOS` or `Net 7 ios` project, and use [Adding images to asset catalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/displaying-an-image#adding-images-to-an-asset-catalog-image-set). Try to copy result to your maui project's `Platforms/iOS`.

Answer (score 0):

By default MAUI application use `Resources/Images` path for images and this path does not accept **@** character as file name. You are trying to use `unselected@2x`, this is the iOS image naming convention for higher resolution but MAUI does not understand this. That's the reason for your error.

**Solution:**

If you want to use your existing resources from your existing Xamarin Forms application instead of convert them in `svg`, you need to tell your MAUI project that you want to use another resource instead of `Resources/Images`.

Let's assume you kept your all images(1x, 2x, 3x) in `Platforms/iOS/Resources` path.
Now write down below code in your `.csproj` to tell your MAUI project that you want to use your resources from `Platforms/iOS/Resources`.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-ios'))">
    <IPhoneResourcePrefix>Platforms/iOS/Resources</IPhoneResourcePrefix>
</PropertyGroup>
```